# Need Value Converter to reference databound object instance

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, valueconverter

So I have an object with multiple attributes that I have bound to my GUI using WPF. Most of the GUI binds directly to properties in my object instance. Some of the GUI elements need to be processed via a ValueConverter first however, as they rely indirectly on an attribute in the bound object. I can create the valueconverter, but was uncertain how to reference the databound object in order to pull the right property values for the conversion.

In pseudo-code I want to do this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    parameter = Databoundobject.EngineRating;
    double weight = EngineList.selfInstance.WeightList[parameter];
}
```

I can find examples that don't reference a databound source in the calling gui, but none that do. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` parameter in the `Convert()` method will hold that raw value from the data-bound source.

Therefore, if you use the converter in a binding to the `EngineRating` property, `value` will hold the value you're looking for.  (You'll need to cast it back to the original type)